# Run Bash Script from Terminal

Tags: kernel, shell, terminal

I have modified a kernel's ramdisk to include a "settings" terminal run bash script.

However, when I type in terminal

```
su
dp
```

I get file is not found.  `dp` exists in the ramdisk as /sbin/dp
I've attempted to create a `symlink` on flashing it with the following

```
symlink("/system/bin/dp", "/sbin/dp");
```

However, I notice the symlink is never created (yes, I have data, system, and cache mounted during the flash process)

How can I ensure `dp` is run via just typing in the above?

Comment: `/system/bin` should be in the PATH for that. Have you made your script executable by the user trying to invoke it (e.g. `chmod 0755 /system/bin/dp`)? I place my "user stuff" in `/system/xbin`, which is also in the path, and never had any issues with them not being executable (unless I forgot those permissions, of course).

Comment: well.... the script is in /sbin/dp   What I want to do is create the dymlink to /system/bin (or /system/xbin)

Comment: Just wondering why. Isn't `/sbin` in your `$PATH`? For me it is. Apart from which: I'm not sure if your call to `symlink()` is correct (not familiar with that one from flashing). For the CLI tool, syntax would be `ln -s <file> <link>`. Maybe you've just got it the wrong way around? The code in your question puts the target (link) first, and the source (file) last.

Comment: Not sure why it's not in my path.   Yeah, I was thinking of executing a shell command to do it...  we'll see how that goes :)